# Active reports multi line text box issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, activereports

I want to split data into multiple lines for a textbox in active reports.

Here is my trail.

I have a report with a text box and its data source is "Name".

And from code behind, I want to append one more value to data source like:

```
dr["Name"] = dr["Name"] + Environment.NewLine + dr["Designation"]
```

When I run the report I could see Name and Designation comes in a same line but I'm expecting in different lines.

Answer (score 0):

As per the **ASP.NET** lifecycle, the page is rendered as an HTML, so `Environment.NewLine` won't work since, it is not at all HTML.

So, you should use the `<br>` tag instead of [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
dr["Name"] = dr["Name"] + "<br>" + dr["Designation"];
```

Or, try it with [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(dr["Name"]);
sb.AppendLine(dr["Designation"]);
```

Comment: I tried even <br> and  "\n" .. nothing worked out for me

Comment: and `\n`? Also, try `<br/>` instead of `<br>`, though it wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: You can also use the [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class to achieve the same.

Comment: Sorry Rakitic.. I tried all options nothing is working for me

Comment: Ok I missed one thing to mention here... when I export this report to PDF line break is working and when I export the same to Excel it is not working

Comment: try it with the newer solution.

Comment: if you see 2 lines of text in Excel output when UseCellMerging is set to False and 1 line of text with UseCellMerging=True then it is old issue that was fixed in ActiveReports 11

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to this. http://www.codepal.co.uk/show/Line_breaks_lost_and_br_tags_show_when_exporting_to_Excel_file but my data is there in a string with <br> tags. Any idea